# Как разместить блоки flexbox на свободном месте?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Почему элементы box не лезут на свободное место под card. Как можно это реализовать используя flexbox?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 24px;
}

.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}

#logo,
#contacts,
#more {
    height: 108px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 22px;
}

#logo {
    width: 122px;
}

#contacts {
    width: 279px;

}

#more {
    width: 513px;
    margin-right: 0;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    padding-bottom: 19px;
    border-bottom: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}

content {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-content: flex-start;
}

#aside {
    width: 184px;
    height: 335px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#card {
    width: 755px;
    height: 211px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#box {
    width: 134px;
    height: 152px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 22px;
}

#box:last-of-type {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div id="logo"></div>
            <div id="contacts"></div>
            <div id="more"></div>
        </header>
        <content>
            <div id="aside"></div>
            <div id="card"></div>
            <div id="box"></div>
            <div id="box"></div>
            <div id="box"></div>
            <div id="box"></div>
            <div id="box"></div>
            <div id="box"></div>
            <div id="box"></div>
        </content>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: не меняя html-структуру - никак. Достигнуть необходимого вам результата можно с помощью grid. Ознкомьтесь: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: А если поменять структуру, но оставить flexbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С измененной структурой html. Так Вы хотели сделать?:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 24px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 1000px;
}

#logo,
#contacts,
#more {
  height: 108px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 22px;
}

#logo {
  width: 122px;
}

#contacts {
  width: 279px;
}

#more {
  width: 513px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 19px;
  border-bottom: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

content {
  flex-grow: 2;
  /* background-color: green;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#left {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20%;
}

#rigth {
  background-color: ;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#card {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
}

#boxWrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="contacts"></div>
    <div id="more"></div>
  </header>
  <content>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="rigth">
      <div id="card"></div>
      <div id="boxWrapper">
        <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
        <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
        <div id="box3" class="box"></div>
        <div id="box4" class="box"></div>
        <div id="box5" class="box"></div>
        <div id="box6" class="box"></div>
        <div id="box7" class="box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </content>
</div>
```